# PHP-SQL LIKE Clause with %

Tags: php, mysql

Database:

```
+----------------------+
+-KEYWORD-|-ANSWER-----+
+----------------------+
+hi,hello | Hey        +
+Who,where| example123 +
+----------------------+
```

User Input in Textbox:

```
Who are you
```

SQL Query

```
SELECT answer FROM chat WHERE keyword LIKE '%Who are You%' LIMIT 0,1
```

Output I am getting is ***Blank***

Expected Output:

```
example123
```

Comment: You should start with the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: `'%Who are You%'` matches any string that contains 'Who are You'! in your table, the column `KEYWORD` does not conatin any string that matches `'%Who are You%'`! Instead you should use `%Who%`, `%Where%`, `%are%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to explode the string to build a request like this :

```
SELECT answer FROM chat WHERE keyword LIKE '%Who%' OR keyword LIKE '%are%' OR keyword LIKE '%you%' LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to get output

$qry="SELECT answer FROM chat WHERE keyword LIKE '%Who%' LIMIT 0,1";

Output:- example123

Answer (score 0):

LIKE `'%Who are You%'` will check a string which contains `Who are You`

Here is the explanation:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Also you can use the query which @Ioic explained

Answer (score -1):

While your search term is equal to `Who are you`, and in the `KEYWORD` column you have just the question's first word. We need to separate the first word from the input statement. Then comparing that first word to the `KEYWORD` column using the `%` wildcard. The result may become:

```
$input = $_POST['textInput'];
$exploded = explode(' ', $input);

$to_compare = $exploded[0];

$q = "SELECT answer FROM chat WHERE keyword LIKE '%$to_compare%' LIMIT 0,1";
```

Comment: This would only search for the first word of the given string.

Comment: Yes that I know. But from the situation the user has asked, it seems he is interested in comparing only the first word of the question.

Comment: @nl-x before downvoting a post you should get a better understanding of the question and the answer and the whole scenario.